# How can I send many files (> 25MiB) at once as attachments?

Tags: gmail

I have 100 compressed pictures. Each of them is 2 MB. I would like to send via email everything at once as attachments (no hosting on Gdrive or somewhere else). Basically pictures will have to be sent in several emails. Is there any way to do it at once?

To put it otherwise, I'm asking for a way to automatically send multiple email messages to send all the files. Ideally not one email per file, but each email should contain as many pictures as possible based on a maximum that I would specify.

I use a Samsung Galaxy S3. I know the max size of the recipient's mailbox and pictures cannot be further compressed. I don't mind filling my recipient's mailbox.

Comment: The sending limit with Gmail is 25MB, regardless of whether you're using Android or not. Other than that, I'm not exactly sure what you're asking for. Are you asking for a way to automatically send multiple email messages to send all the files? Could you [edit] your question and specify that?

Comment: The age of sending big attachments via e-mail is over. Even if GMail would allow big attachments, no one can guarantee that the receiving mail server is also accepting it. What's wrong with hosting the file(s) on GDrive/Dropbox/Whatever and just sending the link?

Comment: @dotVezz Yes, I'm asking for a way to automatically send multiple email messages to send all the files. Ideally not one email per file, but each email should contain as many pictures as possible based on a maximum that I would specify.

Comment: I'm fairly sure there's no real way to do this automatically. The mainstream answer is to use Google Drive, and alternative answers just involve using other cloud storage options. Because of that, there's no real need for anyone to make an app that will do this for you. Like @Flow already asked, is there any reason why you can't use cloud storage?

Comment: @Flow The issue with cloud storage is that I don't want to have those files filling up my cloud account (I prefer to avoid asking the recipient to tell me when he's done, and all unlimited private cloud storage I'm aware of turn out to be crap), or have to deal with expiring links, and I don't want anyone but the recipient to be able to access it.

Comment: If you're that adverse to using cloud storage, then the next best thing to do is to just send 10-12 pictures at once (varies depending on exact size of image(s)). If you need to do this just once, then might as well as suck it up.

Comment: @WoF Well that's the thing: I need to do it more than once. Also, attachments differ for each recipient.

Comment: The best possible workaround to this (or at least the only one I can think of that would work) would be to transfer all of the pictures onto your computer, put the pictures into a folder, and then use a compression program like WinRAR or 7Zip to split up that folder into 25 megabyte chunks, and send them seperately. A self-extracting executable wouldn't work, because gmail doesn't allow for .exe files. Therefore, the recipient would have to have the know-how to extract the files from the compressed folder.

Comment: I really think that using a cloud storage provider is your best bet. If this is for your work, then the expanded storage options will probably be a justified cost. If it's personal, it's still a small fee. I think SkyDrive is something like $10/year for 25+ GiB.

Answer (score -4):

It would be a long and hard way, but if you have enough time and resources you could cross compile the `mail` software of GNU CLI and use it from an Android app.

This way you can be sure the software won't be limiting your messages by attachment size. And if it did you could properly refactor the source code.

Comment: If he's trying to send it through SMTP (He tagged Gmail) Then the SMTP Server's settings will still limit the attachment size and `mail` will fail. And as Flow said, there's no way to guarantee that the receiving server will accept large attachments even if you were to work around the sending limit.

Comment: Yep, the mail servers are enforcing the max mail size, not the mail client/app.

Comment: Indeed I'm not trying to bypass the 25 MB limit, but I'm looking for a way to automatically send multiple email messages to send all the files.

Comment: Tagging _gmail_ is not an enforcement of using a gmail client account. He might be using a non cloud mailing system. The server issues are not to mention here because the asker slightly specified not to worry about recipient account characteristics and limits.

Comment: He mentioned the recipient's email inbox size, the maximum attachment size is an entirely separate thing. As @Flow said already, there's no practical way to send large attachments over email in this day and age. Also, telling a user to cross-compile source code to run on Android is **seriously** not going to be an acceptable answer on this site. You can't expect a user to know how to compile code; they're not even going to be familiar with configuration or syntax of `mail` to begin with. You may want to check our [help] for more information on that.